# Verificar se cookie existe com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, cookies

Tenho um cookie setado com javascript, eu o criei assim:

```
document.cookie='gravado=sim'
```

Não sei como faço pra verificar se ele existe. Preciso fazer uma verificação pois caso ele não  exista, vou redirecionar para outra página, também preciso saber como posso destruir esse cookie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode verificar desta forma

```
if (document.cookie.indexOf("gravado") < 0) {
        alert("O cookie não existe vou criar");
        document.cookie="gravado=sim";
    }
    else {    
        alert("Já está gravado, vou eliminar");  
        document.cookie ="gravado=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;";
    }
```

Comment: Obrigado, e para destruir a sessão eu faço como? no php é bem simples, eu posso usar o comando destroy ou unset e pronto, já no javascript eu não sei como se faz

Comment: Por favor marque a resposta como certa vou corrigir a resposta

Comment: prontinho, marquei

Comment: Eu procurei e tudo que achei foi uma forma de definir o tempo para o cookie expirar, eu queria algo que eu pudesse fazer de imediato, por exemplo, quando eu clicar em algo ou apôs executar uma determinada tarefa eu poder excluir o cookie

Comment: Pode sempre atribuir um valor que determine o seu interesse ex. gravado=eliminado